# Multiple Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

i want to record a user inputed value and at the same time copy a single data from another table. is it possible?

here is my code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO grades (studentnumber,subjectcode)
VALUES
('$_POST[studentnumber]','$_POST[subjectcode]')";

$sql="INSERT INTO grades (course) SELECT course FROM students WHERE studentnumber= '$_POST[studentnumber]'";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record Successfully Added'); location.href = '../instructor/cvsu-sis_students.php';</script>";
```

thanks in advance and sorry for my elementary question.

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). Learn about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one query if that's what you are asking about, also remember to escape the strings to avoid SQL Injection:

```
$P_studentnumber=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentnumber']);
$P_subjectcode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subjectcode']);

$sql="INSERT INTO grades (studentnumber,subjectcode,course) SELECT '$P_studentnumber','$P_subjectcode',course FROM students WHERE studentnumber='$P_studentnumber'";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record Successfully Added'); location.href = '../instructor/cvsu-sis_students.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can use the `UNION` operator to send multiple procedures in one query.

Read this: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Watch out, w3schools' tutorials frequently contain bad practices.  Their PHP section in particular is horrible and full of security vulnerabilities.  You should forget they exist and find a better resource.